# When POSTing to the database, I'm getting a "Can't set headers after they are sent error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, react-redux

In this question I'm posting the complete flow of data for making a sale from start to finish because I don't know where the error lies. In my application I call a function called handlePay() in the Checkout component which in turn calls an action creator called makeSale(). makeSale() then makes a POST request to the server in router.js which will handle this sale in the database using mongoose. The error from the console reads

"/Users/marcushurney/Desktop/P.O.S./node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

I'm not sure if this error exists in my code that communicates with the database in router.js or elsewhere on the front-end. The component on the front-end is called Checkout.jsx and the function that handles a sale is handlePay(), its associated action creator is makeSale().

**Checkout.jsx**

```
handlePay: function() {

        var props = {
            user_id: this.props.activeUser._id, //This sale will belong to the user that is logged in (global state)
            items: [], //All the items in the cart will be added to the sale below (global state)
            total: this.props.cartTotal //Total price of the sale is drawn from the global state
        }


        this.props.cart.map((product) => {
            var item = {};
            item.name = product.name;
            item.product_id = product._id;
            item.cartQuantity = product.cartQuantity;
            item.priceValue = product.price;
            props.items.push(item);
        });

        var jsonProps = JSON.stringify(props); //converts properties into json before sending them to the server

        this.props.makeSale(jsonProps); 
    }
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export function makeSale(props) {

    var config = {headers: {'authorization' : localStorage.getItem('token')}};

    var request = axios.post('/makeSale', props, config); //This will store the sale in the database and also return it

    return {
        type: MAKE_SALE,
        payload: request //Sends sale along to be used in sale_reducer.js
    };

}
```

**router.js**

```
    //Adds a new sale to the database
    //Getting error "can't set headers after they are sent"

    app.post('/makeSale', function(req, res, next){

        var sale = new Sale();
        sale.owner = req.body.user_id;
        sale.total = req.body.total;

        req.body.items.map((item)=> {

            //pushs an item from the request object into the items array           contained in the sale document

            sale.items.push({
                item: item.product_id,
                itemName: item.name,
                cartQuantity: parseInt(item.cartQuantity), //adds cartQuantity to sale
                price: parseFloat(item.priceValue)
            });


            Product.findById(item.product_id)
            .then((product) => {

                //finds the item to be sold in the database and updates its quantity field based on the quantity being sold

                product.quantity -= item.cartQuantity; 

                //resets the product's cartQuantity to 1

                product.cartQuantity = 1;

                product.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) { 
                        return next(err); 
                    } else {
                        return next();
                        // return res.status(200).json(product);
                    }
                });
            }, (error) => {
              return next(error);
            });
        });

        //gives the sale a date field equal to current date

        sale.date = new Date();

        //saves and returns the sale

        sale.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.status(200).json(sale); //Returns the sale so that it can be used in the sale_reducer.js
        });

    });
```

**Here is the sale model for mongoose --> sale.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SalesSchema = new Schema({
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    total: { type: Number, default: 0},
    items: [{
        item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
        itemName: { type: String, default: "no name provided"},
        cartQuantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
        price: { type: Number, default: 0 }
    }],
    date: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Sale', SalesSchema);
```

Comment: This community does not exist so people can post huge walls of code without any context and expect someone else to solve their problems for them.

Comment: I'm wasn't sure where the error was, so I posted all code associated with the flow of data for making a sale from start to finish. Also, I've noticed most people always ask me for more code. How would you suggest I better use stack overflow in the future?

Comment: That's a good observation, people frequently ask questions and provide almost no code. It's good that you posted the code involved in the workflow! This is a big improvement over the average. There are a few ways this post could be improved, specifically providing more context to the error itself (console output, for example) and asking a more specific question. Though it seems you've already solved your problem here and accepted an answer, consider updating your question with more context so future generations can solve their issue more easily.

Comment: I went ahead and added more context to the question and showed the error from the console. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for that! I changed my downvote to an upvote. Thank you for being receptive to feedback and improving your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Product.findById` is asynchronous, and will end up calling `next()` multiple times, which will (most likely) result in attempting to send the response multiple times, which would result in the error you are seeing.

Typically (or always, possibly), you will only want to call `next()` once per middleware.

Try this:

```
"use strict";

app.post('/makeSale', function(req, res, next){

    var sale = new Sale();
    sale.owner = req.body.user_id;
    sale.total = req.body.total;

    return Promise.all(req.body.items.map((item) => {

        // pushs an item from the request object into the items array contained in the sale document
        sale.items.push({
            item: item.product_id,
            itemName: item.name,
            cartQuantity: parseInt(item.cartQuantity, 10), // adds cartQuantity to sale
            price: parseFloat(item.priceValue)
        });

        return Product.findById(item.product_id).then((product) => {

            //finds the item to be sold in the database and updates its quantity field based on the quantity being sold

            product.quantity -= item.cartQuantity; 

            //resets the product's cartQuantity to 1
            product.cartQuantity = 1;
            return product.save();
        });
    }))
    .then(() => {
        //gives the sale a date field equal to current date
        sale.date = new Date();

        //saves and returns the sale
        return sale.save();
    })
    .then(() => {
        return res.status(200).json(sale);
    })
    .catch(next);
});
```

Comment: dvlsg, why do you add a return for Product.findById? Also, what does the use strict do here? This code does indeed solve the problem, but I'm just trying to learn more.

Comment: I return `Product.findById` because it returns a `Promise`, and what we want to do is map `req.body.items` to an array of `Promises` for `Promise.all()` to handle. Additional reading in regards to [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Also note that the code here is executing asynchronously in *parallel*, not sequentially. This could get you into trouble, depending on your data. For example, if you allow multiple separate objects in `req.body.items` which utilize the same `product_id`, those quantity deductions could step on each others toes and you could end up with the wrong amounts. I assumed you didn't allow the same product_id in multiple items since you are using quantities.

Answer (score 1):

In your route, you're calling `next()` for each saved product. You're *also* calling `res.status(200).json(sale)`.

Calling `next()` tells Express that your route handler isn't interested in handling the request, so Express will delegate it to the next matching handler (or a generic *Not Found* handler if there isn't one). You can't subsequently call `next()` again, or send back a response yourself, because you already told Express that you're not interested.

You should rewrite `req.body.items.map(...)` so that it doesn't call `next()` at all.

One solution would be to use [`async.map()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#mapcoll-iteratee-callback). You would then call either `next(error)` (if there is one) *or* `res.json()` in the final callback.

Answer (score 0):

I use JS very rarely for backend, but usually that means you are attempting to set HTTP headers after you are already sent/sending the HTTP body.

Basically: Just make sure your headers are being sent before you print anything to the screen is what that error means.